# Como faço para por uma máscara em um input de Conta Bancária em JS?

Tags: javascript, formulário, input, mask

Preciso criar uma máscara para por o hífen no penúltimo número, automaticamente, desde que ele tenha pelo menos 5 caracteres, em um input de contas bancárias, usando JS puro.
Assim: xxxx-x | xxxxx-x | xxxxxx-x.

```html
<div class="form-group" align="center">
   <label for="cc-nome">Número da conta</label>
   <input type="text" class="line-animation" placeholder="" name="conta"  value="0000-0" required>
   <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Recomendo a vanilla-masker para lidar com máscaras em JS, é bem completa. https://github.com/vanilla-masker/vanilla-masker

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi da Seguinte forma:

```js
function FormataDado(campo, tammax, pos, teclapres) {   
  var keyCode; 
  if (teclapres.srcElement) 
  {
    keyCode = teclapres.keyCode; 
  } else  if (teclapres.target) 
  {
  keyCode = teclapres.which; 
  }
  if (keyCode == 0 || keyCode == 8) { return true; }  
  if ((keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) && keyCode != 88 && (keyCode != 120)) { return false; }  
  var tecla = keyCode; 
  vr = campo.value;   
  vr = vr.replace("-", "");   
  vr = vr.replace("/", ""); 
  
  tam = vr.length;
  if (tam < tammax && tecla != 8) 
  { tam = vr.length + 1; } 
  if (tecla == 8) 
{
    tam = tam - 1; 
}
  if (tecla == 8 || tecla == 88 || tecla >= 48 && tecla <= 57 || tecla >= 96 && tecla <= 105 || tecla == 120) 
{
  if (tam <= 2) 
{
      campo.value = vr; 
}
  if (tam > pos && tam <= tammax) 
{
campo.value = vr.substr(0, tam - pos) + "-" + vr.substr(tam - pos, tam); 
}
}
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="line-animation" placeholder="" name="conta" id="ContaB" value="0000" required onkeypress="return FormataDado(this,12,1,event);"/>
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
    function formatarContaBancaria(input) {
      // remove todos os caracteres que não são números
      let numeroConta = input.value.replace(/\D/g, '');

      // adiciona o hífen no quinto último caractere, caso a conta tenha pelo menos 5 caracteres
      if (numeroConta.length >= 5) {
        numeroConta = `${numeroConta.slice(0, -1)}-${numeroConta.slice(-1)}`;
      }

      // atualiza o valor do campo com a conta formatada
      input.value = numeroConta;
    }


    const campoConta = document.querySelector('input[name="conta"]');
    campoConta.addEventListener('input', () => formatarContaBancaria(campoConta));
```

```html
<div class="form-group" align="center">
    <label for="cc-nome">Número da conta</label>
    <input type="text" class="line-animation" placeholder="" name="conta" value="0000-0" required>
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).